# How to change the tab indicator width in tabLayout android? I am using tabLayout with viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I am using a tabLayout and I want the tabIndicator width to be smaller than the tab. I have done a lot of searching and could not find a good solution.

If there is a way around my situation, please do tell. I would greatly appreciate the solution
Thanks

Comment: Show your research. If something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480675/1531971 doesn't help, we need to know what exactly the problem is that you are seeing. Read [ask] and maybe show some code.