# Android TabLayout Indicator drawable color is not visible also unable to add custom width

Tags: android, android-view, android-tablayout, material-components-android, material-components

I want to use custom drawable for TabLayout indicator like this
[image]

but it is not showing the colors

[image: lso]

also unable to add custom width. As you can see that design has width that is not more than width of text, how I could to do that?

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/lines"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
                        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#000"
                        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceTab"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/bluey_grey" />
```

I've tried with both SVG and PNG

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default style applies a tint to the `tabIndicator`.
You can add in your layout (or in your style) the **`tabIndicatorColor`**.

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/..."
        ..>
```

You can use a color or you can use `"@null"` (it depends by your original drawable).

About the tab width you can use the **`app:tabMinWidth`** attribute.

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
        app:tabMinWidth="125dp"
        ..>
```

[image]

Comment: When I just use `app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"` it is not showing any in indicator line

Comment: `app:tabMinWidth` is working for whole tab not for tab indicator

Comment: @Bills About the width sorry, my bad. You should add also `app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"` to achieve a result as in the screen.

Comment: I don't want to match the indicator width with Tab but want to hard code the width of indicator i.e 46dp

Comment: @Bills In this case it is not so simple. There isn't an attribute to do it. There is an open issue on [googletracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128641683). Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480675/android-tab-layout-wrap-tab-indicator-width-with-respect-to-tab-title): it is a workaround but I've tried it.