# How to adjust tabRow indicator width according to the text above it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

i want to adjust tabrow's indicator width according to text above like this.
But I don't know how to manipulate the width of the indicator in a generic way.

##### Intended:

[image]

##### My Code:

```
TabRow(
                    // Our selected tab is our current page
                    selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    indicator = { tabPositions ->
                        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                            Modifier
                                .offset(0.dp, -6.dp)
                                .pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions)
                        )
                    }
                )
```

##### My Result:

[image]

I will be glad if you can guide me.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480675/android-tab-layout-wrap-tab-indicator-width-with-respect-to-tab-title

Comment: In compose there is no setTabIndicatorFullWidth so @sasikumar, it can not referred that question

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately wrap the text size isn't supported yet!, but you can copy and modify the whole TabRow or just use padding like so:

[image]

```
indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    Modifier
                        .pagerTabIndicatorOffset(
                            pagerState = pagerState,
                            tabPositions = tabPositions
                        )
                         // look here
                        .padding(horizontal = 40.dp),
                    color = Color.White,
                    height = 2.dp,
                )

            }
```

Comment: pagerTabIndicatorOffset not found

Comment: @SureshMaidaragi Did you add accompanist pager dependencies? 

`// Compose Pager
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:$accompanist"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:$accompanist"`





also it is deprecated and you should use 

`androidx.compose.foundation.pager`

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.example.scrollabletabrow

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.core.FastOutSlowInEasing
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateDpAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.offset
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentSize
import androidx.compose.material.ScrollableTabRow
import androidx.compose.material.Tab
import androidx.compose.material.TabPosition
import androidx.compose.material.TabRowDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.composed
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.debugInspectorInfo
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.scrollabletabrow.ui.theme.ScrollableTabRowTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
            val tabs = listOf("Fruits", "Vegetables", "Meats", "Miscellaneous")
            ScrollableTabRowTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                CustomScrollableTabRow(
                    tabs = tabs,
                    selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
                ) { tabIndex ->
                    selectedTabIndex = tabIndex
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomScrollableTabRow(
    tabs: List<String>,
    selectedTabIndex: Int,
    onTabClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val tabWidths = remember {
        val tabWidthStateList = mutableStateListOf<Dp>()
        repeat(tabs.size) {
            tabWidthStateList.add(0.dp)
        }
        tabWidthStateList
    }
    ScrollableTabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
        contentColor = Color.White,
        edgePadding = 0.dp,
        indicator = { tabPositions ->
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                modifier = Modifier.customTabIndicatorOffset(
                    currentTabPosition = tabPositions[selectedTabIndex],
                    tabWidth = tabWidths[selectedTabIndex]
                )
            )
        }
    ) {
        tabs.forEachIndexed { tabIndex, tab ->
            Tab(
                selected = selectedTabIndex == tabIndex,
                onClick = { onTabClick(tabIndex) },
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = tab,
                        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                            tabWidths[tabIndex] =
                                with(density) { textLayoutResult.size.width.toDp() }
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

fun Modifier.customTabIndicatorOffset(
    currentTabPosition: TabPosition,
    tabWidth: Dp
): Modifier = composed(
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        name = "customTabIndicatorOffset"
        value = currentTabPosition
    }
) {
    val currentTabWidth by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = tabWidth,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing)
    )
    val indicatorOffset by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = ((currentTabPosition.left + currentTabPosition.right - tabWidth) / 2),
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing)
    )
    fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.BottomStart)
        .offset(x = indicatorOffset)
        .width(currentTabWidth)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable the indicator and draw it underneath the text in your Tab composable.  Unfortunately, you'll lose the animation when selecting a tab.